# What kind of Orbea bike do I have?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

Army Green Orbea
EN ISO 4210-2
There is a Ming seat on the bike
I can’t find any Numbers or letters etched into the bike or on a sticker and stuck onto the bike

Comment: Welcome to Bike Exchange.  If you could take some pictures of the front and rear derailleurs, the crankset, the brakes, and the shifters; pictures that will have some identifying names or model numbers on the items, we would have a better chance of narrowing this down for you.  It can help identify the range of years that the bike was produced.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the rear stays probably one of the urban bikes. Maybe the Vector or one of its cousins.

https://www.orbea.com/pt-en/bicycles/urban/vector/cat/vector-10

What does the box graphic on the side of the fork say. That graphic seems to hold the model name.

Comment: I confirm the model name is on the fork, it is the Carpe. There were like three trim levels, this looks in the middle judging by the hydraulic brakes.